# Some problems about Python inherited classmethod

Tags: python, class-method

I have this code:

```
from typing import Callable, Any


class Test(classmethod):
    def __init__(self, f: Callable[..., Any]):
        super().__init__(f)

    def __get__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print(args)  # why out put is (None, <class '__main__.A'>) where form none  why no parameter 123
        # where was it called
        return super().__get__(*args,**kwargs)


class A:
    @Test
    def b(cls,v_b):
        print(cls,v_b)

A.b(123)
```

Why the output is `(None, <class '__main__.A'>)`? Where did `None` come form and why is it not the *parameter* 123, which is the value I called it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__get__` method is called when the *method* `b` is retrieved from the `A` class. It has nothing to do with the actual *calling* of `b`.

To illustrate this, separate the access to `b` from the actual call of `b`:

```
print("Getting a reference to method A.b")
method = A.b
print("I have a reference to the method now. Let's call it.")
method()
```

This results in this output:

```
Getting a reference to method A.b
(None, <class '__main__.A'>)
I have a reference to the method now. Let's call it.
<class '__main__.A'> 123
```

So you see, it is normal that the output in `__get__` does not show anything about the argument you call `b` with, because you haven't made the call yet.

---

The output `None, <class '__main__.A'>` is in line with the [Python documentation on `__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__):

> `object.__get__(self, instance, owner=None)`
>
> Called to get the attribute of the owner class (class attribute access) or of an instance of that class (instance attribute access). The optional *owner* argument is the owner class, while *instance* is the instance that the attribute was accessed through, or `None` when the attribute is accessed through the *owner*.

In your case you are using it for accessing an attribute (`b`) of a **class** (`A`) -- not of an instance of `A` -- so that explains the `instance` argument is `None` and the `owner` argument is your class `A`.

---

The second output, made with `print(cls,v_b)`, will print `<class '__main__.A'>` for `cls`, because that is what happens when you call *class* methods (as opposed to *instance* methods). Again, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> When a class attribute reference (for class `C`, say) would yield a class method object, it is transformed into an instance method object whose `__self__` attribute is `C`.

Your case is described here, where `A` is the class, and so the first parameter (which you called `cls`) will get as value `A`.

Comment: very thanks to u but cls Where did it come from

Comment: That sounds like a new question? But that is what is expected according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__)

Comment: Added the explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply multiple decorators on the same function, for example,

- first (and outer) decorator could be a classmethod
- and the second (doing your stuff) could define a wrapper, where you could accept your arguments as usual

```py
In [4]: def test_deco(func):
   ...:     def wrapper(cls, *args, **kwds):
   ...:         print("cls is", cls)
   ...:         print("That's where 123 should appear>>>", args, kwds)
   ...:         return func(cls, *args, **kwds)
   ...: 
   ...:     return wrapper
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: class A:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     @test_deco
   ...:     def b(cls, v_b):
   ...:         print("That's where 123 will appear as well>>>", v_b)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: A.b(123)
```

```
cls is <class '__main__.A'>
That's where 123 should appear>>> (123,) {}
That's where 123 will appear as well>>> 123

In [5]:
```

> It's too much trouble to use two at a time i want only use one like it

It is possible to define a decorator applying a couple of other decorators:

```py
def my_super_decorator_doing_everything_at_once(func):
    return classmethod(my_small_decorator_doing_almost_everything(func))
```

That works because decorators notation

```py
@g
@f
def x(): ...
```

is a readable way to say

```
def x(): ...
x = g(f(x))
```

Comment: sry I don't quite understand Can I merge this way? How should I use it?

Comment: I succeeded. Thank you very much

Comment: @trincot, yes, that tone from my side was not necessary, I’m sorry.